# Refactor (transpose) array to unique keys

Tags: php, arrays, refactoring

I'm transposing some db results for statistic generation.

Original array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [a] => apple
            [b] => beer
            [c] => chocolate
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [a] => aardvark
            [b] => bear
            [c] => chupacabra
        )
)
```

Desired result:

```
Array
(
    [a] => Array
        (
            [0] => apple
            [1] => aardvark
        )
    [b] => Array
        (
            [0] => beer
            [1] => bear
        )

    [c] => Array
        (
            [0] => chocolate
            [1] => chupacabra
        )
)
```

Sample code:

```
$stats[] = array(
    'a' => 'apple',
    'b' => 'beer',
    'c' => 'chocolate'
);

$stats[] = array(
    'a' => 'aardvark',
    'b' => 'bear',
    'c' => 'chupacabra'
);

foreach (array_keys($stats[0]) as $key){
    $data[$key] = array_column($stats, $key);
}
```

The above code is working fine using [array_keys](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) and [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) (php 5.5).

- Is there a more elegant way or php function to achieve the same result?
- What is the common name for this kind of re-factoring?

EDIT:

As per comments below the correct term for this is "transposing"

Comment: That's called "transposing a matrix" in mathematics.

Comment: @sectus That is a beautiful solution but does not work for this example as it does not preserve the string keys

Comment: @Blazemonger thanks for the terminology pointer, post as answer?

Comment: `Refactor` has different meaning.

Comment: Now I understand that, and hopefully people who find this question using that incorrect term (like myself) will be educated by your answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had thought there was an `array_*` function for that sort of thing, but I couldn't remember so I went to the PHP documentation Turns out that `array_merge_recursive` does just what you want.

```
array_merge_recursive($array1, $array2)
```

You have your arrays to combine in a single array, so you'll have to populate the function's arguments with the contents of the array.

```
call_user_func_array("array_merge_recursive", $stats)
```

That one line should do what you are looking for.